# ANTLR4 project wont display anything in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, antlr4, lexer, parser-generator

Working from the book "The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference," I'm trying to run the **ArrayInit.g4** example in Eclipse. I've managed to generate the necessary java files and others, but when I run the example and enter values into the console and hit Enter, nothing happens *(pages 29 and 30)*.

**ArrayInit.g4**

```
/** Grammars always start with a grammar header. This grammar is called
* ArrayInit and must match the filename: ArrayInit.g4
*/
grammar ArrayInit;

@header
{
    package com.foo.bar;
}

/** A rule called init that matches comma-separated values between {...}. */
init : '{' value (',' value)* '}' ; // must match at least one value
/** A value can be either a nested array/struct or a simple integer (INT) */
value : init
| INT
;
// parser rules start with lowercase letters, lexer rules with uppercase
INT : [0-9]+ ; // Define token INT as one or more digits
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

**Main.java**

```
package com.foo.bar;

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        // create a CharStream that reads from standard input
        ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(System.in);
        // create a lexer that feeds off of input CharStream
        ArrayInitLexer lexer = new ArrayInitLexer(input);
        // create a buffer of tokens pulled from the lexer
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        // create a parser that feeds off the tokens buffer
        ArrayInitParser parser = new ArrayInitParser(tokens);
        ParseTree tree = parser.init(); // begin parsing at init rule

        // Create a generic parse tree walker that can trigger callbacks
        ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
        // Walk the tree created during the parse, trigger callbacks
        walker.walk(new ShortToUnicodeString(), tree);
        System.out.println(); // print a \n after translation
    }
}
```

**Entered into console:**
{99, 3, 451}

**Expected output:**
"\u0063\u0003\u01c3"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you enter {99, 3, 451} press enter for newline and than **ctrl + Z** (at least on windows) to say that you are finished with input, than it will work. 
Eventually in the book you will get to "10.1 Building a Calculator with Grammar Actions" and subtitle "Building an Interactive Calculator" and in there you will find some nicer ways for providing keyboard input.